# What statistical method should I use to model data?

Tags: spss, modeling, model

I am trying to model a continuous numerical variable using a binary fingerprint (0 and 1)- I have used decision trees to model this, is this the best method to use? If not, what method would be best and why?
Thanks in advance.

More Info: I have a fingerprint of almost 1000 bits (1 or 0), and I want to explore how well this predicts a continuous variable , I have around 10'000 entries with values from about -10.00 to 10.00. I want to make a predictive model to find bits that predict the continuous variable. I have used a decision tree in SPSS and this can predict a test set reasonably, is this the best way to model what I have?

Comment: You need to give much more details of your problem for this to be answerable!

Comment: Sorry, I have a fingerprint of almost 1000 bits (1 or 0), and I want to explore how well this predicts a continuous variable , I have around 10'000 entries with values from about -10.00 to 10.00. I want to make a predictive model to find bits that predict the continuous variable. I have used a decision tree in SPSS and this can predict a test set reasonably, but I was expecting it to do better than it did so I'm wondering if I have used the wrong predictive model?

Comment: You should edit that new information into the original question, together with some more, preferably in the language of the application. How many variables? Why are you not satisfied with the results from the tree model? ...

Comment: Ah, done that, thanks.  The fingerprint contains 1000 bits, which I have used as the variables in decision trees to model a continuous variable. Prior assumptions were that the fingerprint should add a lot more than they have done, I'm just not sure if decision trees are the strongest statistics to use to predict what I have.

Comment: There's no "best" method, just what works good enough for your purposes. Aside from posting more info on your data, what was your observed AUC? Since you seem to like decision trees, have you tried XGBOOST?

Comment: It's not so much my preference, only that I'm unsure what else I can use in the short time frame I have to analyse my data for my thesis. What info on my data would be useful?

Comment: I haven't done AUC as the data should be a linear relationship, the prediction has a slightly higher R2 than linear regression which is the usual standard, but it's a difference of 0.01, so it's pretty much the same - we were expecting an improvement by using the fingerprint.